# How to call another sub in the end of one?

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to put a simple code in the end of a procedure to call another existent Sub procedure, but I get the following compile error: Expected Sub, Function, or Property. The code is:

```
Dim Teste2Sigma As VbMsgBoxResult
        Teste2Sigma = MsgBox("Deseja ignorar as razões 6/8 e 7/6, de cada amostra, que não passaram no teste 2 sigma?", vbYesNo)
        If Teste2Sigma = vbYes Then Call Teste2Sigma
        If Teste2Sigma = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
     End If
```

It is in the end of a sub which is running perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `Teste2Sigma` as a `VbMsgBoxResult` at the top and then you try to `Call` it.  I'm assuming that you have a sub of that name too.  If so, you should rename your `VbMsgBoxResult` variable, perhaps to `msgBoxResult`.  For example:

```
Dim msgBoxResult As VbMsgBoxResult
msgBoxResult = MsgBox("Deseja ignorar as razões 6/8 e 7/6, de cada amostra, que não passaram no teste 2 sigma?", vbYesNo)
If msgBoxResult = vbYes Then Call Teste2Sigma
If msgBoxResult = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```